# C++ - Finding multiples & eliminating common ones

Tags: c++

I've written out a program that asks the user for two numbers and a threshold. The program should find all the multiples of both the numbers below the specific threshold. I've written a  for loop that will run through the numbers each time and check whether any of the multiples are also multiples of the other inputted number. If it is, it print it out. But strangely, when I run this program, it doesn't print anything out! It's quite frustrating!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int mult1, mult2, threshold;
    cout << "Enter first multiple: ";
    cin >> mult1;
    cout << "Enter second multiple: ";
    cin >> mult2;
    cout << "Enter the threshold: ";
    cin >> threshold;
    for (int i = 1; i < threshold; i++)
    {
        int check1 = mult1*i;
        int check2 = mult2*i;
        if (check1/check2 == 1)
            cout << check1 << endl;
    }
    char response;
    cin >> response;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Vote to close: Asking strangers to spot errors in your code by inspection is not productive.  You should identify (or at least isolate) the problem by using a debugger or print statements, and then come back with a more specific question.

Comment: Your logic seems incorrect. How could product of two different numbers multiplied with the same number would give the same result ? Ex: 5*1, 7*1 yields same result ?

Comment: As Mahesh says, that code doesn't seem correct. Why dont you use: `if (i%mult1==0&&i%mult2==0)` to know if `i` is multiple of both numbers?.

Answer (score 2):

Add `endl` after each line displayed.
By default, cout has a cache and it does not display immediately.
`endl` flush the output and add a line break.

```
cout << "Enter first multiple: " << endl;
```

Comment: Actually, `cin` has a little-known feature: reading `cin` automatically flushes `cout`. So this is completely untrue.

Comment: You can actually `tie` any `ostream` to any `ios`: [ios::tie](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/tie/)

Comment: @Potatoswatter: and anyway all buffers will be emptied before the programs stops. `endl` is pretty much useless in most situations.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this question doesn't sufficiently specify the problem.

> The program should find all the multiples of both the numbers below the specific threshold.

Do you want to find all numbers that are multiples of *either* input number or *both* input numbers? If *both*, then note that the result will simply be all multiples of the [least common multiple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of the inputs.

One helpful tip: C++ has the [`%` operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) which can tell you if one number is a multiple of another.

```
if ( a % b == 0 ) {
    // a is a multiple of b
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this seems like homework, I will not give you the complete answer, but just a hint:

`if (check1/check2 == 1)` means `check1` is somewhere in `[check2, 2*check2)` which is not at all what you want. You may want to take a look at the `%` operator.

Also, if you want to print values less than `threshold`, then `check1` should be less than `threshold`, which mean `i` should go up to `threshold/mult1`.

Comment: Ever heard about integer division? `check1/check2==1` means `check1>=check2 && check1<2*check2`.

Comment: @ipc, yeah sorry, I meant to tell him that's not what he wants, forgot about the types.